# How to remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string except period and space in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove all non alphanumeric characters from a string except period and space in Excel.  A solution using VBA rather than pure excel functions be just fine.

Comment: See this question, except for period/space part. Your pattern would be like [A-Z,a-z,0-9,\.,\s] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789948/remove-non-numeric-characters-from-excel

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Insert this function into a new module in the Visual Basic Editor:

```
Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122: 'include 32 if you want to include space
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```

Now you can use this as a User Define Function, i.e. if your data is in cell `A1`, place this formula in an empty cell `=AlphaNumericOnly(A1)`.

If you want to convert a large range directly, i.e. replace all the non-alphanumeric characters without leaving the source, you can do this with another VBA routine:

```
Sub CleanAll()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1500").Cells 'adjust sheetname and range accordingly
        rng.Value = AlphaNumericOnly(rng.Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

Simply place this sub in the same module and execute it. Be aware though, that this will replace any formulas in the range.

Comment: Albert, that was fast, thank you.  I will try it tomorrow. As I said I know little about excel could you explain how to use the function I need to run it across my entire excel sheet. This will usually have 11 columns and about 1500 rows but this can very.  Thank you this is much appreciated

Comment: For anyone who wants to add or subtract Characters from the above to tool it to there needs here is a reference sheet: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/ascii-character-chart-HA001133136.aspx

Comment: +1 Good point! Alternatively, I simply used `? Asc("A")` in the debug console to get the ASCII code...

Comment: The link Tim provided is no longer functional.  Here's a new one:  [link](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for a more elegant solution than the one I came up with.  I was going to use ashleedawg's code above as it certainly is neater than my code.  Ironically, mine ran 30% quicker.  If speed is important (say you have a few million to do), try this:

```vb
Public Function AlphaNumeric(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If InStr(1, "01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz. ", Mid(str, i, 1)) Then AlphaNumeric = AlphaNumeric & Mid(str, i, 1)
    Next
End Function
```

There's a surprise around every corner with VBA.  I'd never imagine this would be quicker...

Answer (score 12):

Here' an alternate method of removing "whatever characters you want" from a string using pattern matching.

- The example below removes everything *except* letters, numbers, spaces and periods (`[A-Z.a-z 0-9]`)
- For improved efficiency it also utilizes VBA's [seamless conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244433/8112776) between Strings and Byte Arrays:

> ## `cleanString` Function:
>
> ```
> Function cleanString(str As String) As String
>     Dim ch, bytes() As Byte: bytes = str
>     For Each ch In bytes
>         If Chr(ch) Like "[A-Z.a-z 0-9]" Then cleanString = cleanString & Chr(ch)
>     Next ch
> End Function
> ```

---

### More Information:

- For more about creating patterns for the `Like` operator, see:

  - [VBA: **Like Operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator#pattern-options) description
  - better info in the [VB.NET: **Like Operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) description
- More about how [**Byte Arrays and Strings are basically interchangeable**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51244433/8112776)

Comment: Nice ! This is the most elegant and probably the fastest one. If speed is an issue, I would try `For i =...` vs `For each...`

Comment: Would using a for loop vs foreach really be reasonably different in performance?

Comment: Fyi Though a late response to your valuable post+:), you might be interested in my alternate function [`AlphaNum()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723672/how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters-from-a-string-except-period-and-sp/74679416#74679416) *grouping* characters into categories which allows to include even ►accented and ►diacritic characters by a string search shift. @ashleedawg

Answer (score 2):

I have written the following code and it works as far as I tested it, it consists of two functions. The first checks whether a string is alphanumeric and the second makes the replacement (it also removes spaces)

```
Public Function Isalphanumeric(cadena As String) As Boolean

    Select Case Asc(UCase(cadena))
        Case 65 To 90 'letras
            Isalphanumeric = True
        Case 48 To 57 'numeros
            Isalphanumeric = True
        Case Else
            Isalphanumeric = False

    End Select

End Function
```

And here goes the remove function

```
Function RemoveSymbols_Enhanced(InputString As String) As String

 Dim InputString As String
 Dim CharactersArray()
 Dim i, arrayindex, longitud As Integer
 Dim item As Variant


 i = 1
 arrayindex = 0
 longitud = Len(InputString)

'We create an array with non alphanumeric characters
 For i = 1 To longitud

  If Isalphanumeric(Mid(InputString, i, 1)) = False Then
    ReDim Preserve CharactersArray(arrayindex)
    CharactersArray(arrayindex) = Mid(InputString, i, 1)
    arrayindex = arrayindex + 1

  End If

  Next

 'For each non alphanumeric character we do a replace
 For Each item In CharactersArray
  item = CStr(item)
  InputString = Replace(InputString, item, "")
 Next


End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get alphanumeric characters including spaces, +- signs and (point)commata**

The tricky helper function `getCodes()` called by **`AlphaNum()`** groups each character into five categories, where

- category 4 corresponds to *digits*,
- 5 to any *letters*, not only from A-Z, but **including** even ►accented or ►diacritic ones.

By looping to the returned `codes` array you are in the position to get only the relevant alphanum characters
or allowed signs.

```
Function AlphaNum(ByVal s As String, Optional info As Boolean = False) As String
'a) group characters into code categories
    Dim codes: codes = getCodes(s, info)
'b) check codes returning only alpha nums
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(codes)
        Dim char As String: char = Mid$(s, i, 1)
        Dim okay As Boolean: okay = False
        Select Case codes(i)
        '   AlphaNum: 4=digits, 5=letters
            Case Is >= 4: okay = True
        '   other characters
            Case 2          ' allowing space, minus or comma
                If InStr(" ,-", char) <> 0 Then okay = True
            Case 3          ' allowing plus or point
                If InStr(".+", char) <> 0 Then okay = True
        End Select
        If okay Then ii = ii + 1: codes(ii) = char
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve codes(1 To ii)
    AlphaNum = Join(codes, vbNullString)
End Function
```

**Helper functions**

```
Function Char2Arr(ByVal s As String)
'Purp.: assign single characters to array
    s = StrConv(s, vbUnicode)
    Char2Arr = Split(s, vbNullChar, Len(s) \ 2)
End Function
```

```
Function getCodes(s, Optional info As Boolean = False)
'Purp.: group characters into five categories
    Const CATEG As String = "' - . 0 A"
    Dim arr:   arr = Char2Arr(s)
    Dim chars: chars = Split(CATEG)
    getCodes = Application.Match(arr, chars)  'No 3rd zero-argument!!
    'optional display in immediate window
    If info Then
        Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
        Debug.Print Join(getCodes, "|")
    End If
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
    Dim s As String
    s = "Alpha, -8.9 +äæçñöüéêëÿ'!$""#$%&()*/:;<=>?@|¶"

    Debug.Print "~~> " & AlphaNum(s, info:=True)
```

**Display in VB editor's immediate window**

```
A|l|p|h|a|,| |-|8|.|9| |+|ä|æ|ç|ñ|ö|ü|é|ê|ë|ÿ|'|!|$|"|#|$|%|&|(|)|*|/|:|;|<|=|>|?|@|||¶ 
5|5|5|5|5|2|2|2|4|3|4|2|3|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|5|1|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|2|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3
Alpha, -8.9 +äæçñöüéêëÿ
```