# get rid of white space no matter where in the string

Tags: vba

I am trying to remove white space no matter what position it is in -- within a string.  I have to write the code in VBA.  Below is what I have written so far.  When I use chr(32) or space(1), VBA seems to throw a fit and not like what I have written.
In other words, I want to pass a string to the cleanFunction:
FB 10-0073
and have it return:
FB100073.  Notice, no white space.

```
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?,-" 'chr(32),chr(95),chr(160),chr(47),chr(45)"  'modify as needed
Private Const EXPC As String = "EXP_C"

Public Function cleanString(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim newString As String
    Dim char As Variant
    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
        newString = Trim(Replace(text, char, ""))
    Next
    cleanString = newString
End Function
```

Comment: `FB 10-0073` and have it return: `FB100073` is the `-` missing a typo or what?

Comment: the function should get rid of the special characters and whitespace.  it does a good job of getting rid of characters.  The hyphen is one of them.  (-)

Comment: I'd take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40929620/4088852)

Answer (score 2):

## Get Rid Off Characters

### 1.5 Problems

- You don't have the space character in the variant (probably a typo).
- You are doing the trim-replace always on the initial text, so what
  ever character is last in the variant ("-" in your case) will be replaced, the others
  will not.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Function cleanString(ByVal CleanText As String) As String
    Const SpecialCharacters As String = _
            "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?,-,_,/, " ' chr(160)
    Dim newString As String
    Dim char As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    newString = CleanText
    char = Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(char)
        newString = Replace(newString, char(i), "")
    Next
    cleanString = newString
End Function
```